# Why does the button are not adjusting on mobile screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am currently working on a webpage of mine for my mother students and i am struggling in this one, which is when i open it on the mobile the button are not adjusting , everything are adjusting except for the buttons they are overlapping each other.
and also im new on web developing

here is the backend of the button on my index

```js
const showMenu = (toggleId, navId) =>{
    const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
    nav = document.getElementById(navId)

    if(toggle && nav){
        toggle.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            nav.classList.toggle('show')
        })
    }
}
showMenu('nav-toggle','nav-menu')

/*===== ACTIVE AND REMOVE MENU =====*/
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link');   

function linkAction(){
  /*Active link*/
  navLink.forEach(n => n.classList.remove('active'));
  this.classList.add('active');
  
  /*Remove menu mobile*/
  const navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-menu')
  navMenu.classList.remove('show')
}
navLink.forEach(n => n.addEventListener('click', linkAction));
```

```css
.button{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  text-align:center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: .75rem 2.5rem;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

#but0{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  text-align:center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: .75rem 2.5rem;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  border-radius: .5rem;



}

#but1{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute; right: 42%;

  color: #fff;
  padding: .75rem 2.5rem;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

#but2{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute; right: 10%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: .75rem 2.5rem;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  border-radius: .5rem;
}
```

```html
 <a target="_blank" href="#" class="button" id="but0">Online Regulations
                        <p id="settings-note">*Download here</p></a>
            
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdZ5dzDCllrRvxbugJOvGCzka4T92vBmaNizDaIVY6uYSzGVQ/viewform?usp=sf_link"
                       class="button" id="but1">Attendance
                        <p id="settings-note">*Link here</p>

                    <a target="_blank" href="#"  class="button" id="but2">Schedules
                        <p id="settings-note">*Download here</p></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically setting the position to absolute, will take the elements out of the normal flow of the webpage, and position them as per the properties you give them. Since you have a `right` property on the second and third buttons, they place themselves at specific distances from the right edge, regardless of what they overlap with.

Try changing the css and markup to the following. I've used flex to properly space the buttons.

```css
#buttonWrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: .75rem 2.5rem;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  border-radius: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id='buttonWrapper'>
  <a target="_blank" href="#" class="button" id="but0">
    Online Regulations
    <p id="settings-note">*Download here</p>
  </a>

  <a target="_blank" href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdZ5dzDCllrRvxbugJOvGCzka4T92vBmaNizDaIVY6uYSzGVQ/viewform?usp=sf_link" class="button" id="but1">
    Attendance
    <p id="settings-note">*Link here</p>
  </a>

  <a target="_blank" href="#" class="button" id="but2">
    Schedules
    <p id="settings-note">*Download here</p>
  </a>
</div>
```